# String transformation in R | Grouping words of a string

Tags: regex, r, string

I want to group the words of string(given below)

```
text="Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetuer"
```

like this

```
textNew="Lorem ipsum,ipsum dolor,dolor sit,sit amet,amet consectetuer"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through `gsub` function,

```
> text="Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetuer"
> f <- gsub(",([^,]*)", " \\1,\\1", text, perl=TRUE)
> result <- gsub(",[^,]*$", "", f, perl=TRUE)
> result
[1] "Lorem ipsum,ipsum dolor,dolor sit,sit amet,amet consectetuer"
```

Comment: Which is faster? the one using gsub or lapply ? coz i need to run this on a large set text files

Comment: @510947, I didn't benchmark, but I'm guessing the `gsub` here will be faster than the others.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
x <- strsplit(text, ",")[[1]]
paste0(sapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(z) paste(x[c(z, z+1)], collapse = " ")), collapse = ",")
[1] "Lorem ipsum,ipsum dolor,dolor sit,sit amet,amet consectetuer"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ahh got something similar.

```
text="Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetuer"
text2 <- unlist(strsplit(text, ","))
textNew=paste0(sapply(1:(length(text2)-1),function(i,y=text2){paste(y[i],y[i+1])}),collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
  library(stringr)
   txt2 <- str_extract_all(text, "[^,]+")[[1]]
   paste(paste(txt2[-length(txt2)],txt2[-1],sep=" "), collapse=", ")
   #[1] "Lorem ipsum, ipsum dolor, dolor sit, sit amet, amet consectetuer"
```

Or

```
  library(gsubfn)
   paste(strapply(text, "([^,]+),(?=([^,]+))", paste, backref= -2, perl=TRUE)[[1]], collapse=",")
   #[1] "Lorem ipsum,ipsum dolor,dolor sit,sit amet,amet consectetuer"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this functions from [`stringi` package](http://stringi.rexamine.com)

```
require(stringi)
text <- "Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetuer"
words <- stri_split_fixed(text,",")[[1]]
stri_join(words[-length(words)]," ",words[-1],collapse = ", ")
## [1] "Lorem ipsum, ipsum dolor, dolor sit, sit amet, amet consectetuer"
```

some benchmarks :)

```
stringi <- function(){
  words <- stri_split_fixed(text,",")[[1]]
  stri_join(words[-length(words)]," ",words[-1],collapse = ", ")
}

gsubAvinash <- function(){
  f <- gsub(",([^,]*)", " \\1,\\1", text, perl=TRUE)
  result <- gsub(",[^,]*$", "", f, perl=TRUE)
  result
}

strsplitBeggineR <- function(){
  x <- strsplit(text, ",")[[1]]
  paste0(sapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(z) paste(x[c(z, z+1)], collapse = " ")), collapse = ",")
}

stringrAkrun <- function(){
  txt2 <- str_extract_all(text, "[^,]+")[[1]]
  paste(paste(txt2[-length(txt2)],txt2[-1],sep=" "), collapse=", ")
}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(stringi(), gsubAvinash(),strsplitBeggineR(),stringrAkrun())
Unit: microseconds
               expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
          stringi()   8.657  10.6090  16.5005  17.6730  41.058   100
      gsubAvinash()  14.506  17.1055  20.2105  22.2040  97.399   100
 strsplitBeggineR()  53.609  59.7755  64.9470  68.3105 121.767   100
     stringrAkrun() 148.036 157.4715 162.4885 168.2880 342.471   100
```