# Using stringr's word() to repeat and group a sentence

Tags: r, string, paste, stringr

Here's a fun one.  I'm trying to do exactly what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441766/string-transformation-in-r-grouping-words-of-a-string) is doing.  That is, repeating and grouping words.

The catch with this question is that I'd like to do it purely with `stringr`'s `word()` function with a `paste0` wrapper.  Take the following `sentence`

```
sentence <- "Jane saw a cat and then Jane sat down."
```

The exact result would be

```
[1] "Jane saw, saw a, a cat, cat and, and then, then Jane, Jane sat, sat down."
```

I've gotten this far, but `word()` leaves an extra `""` at the end of this string, likely due to the way I've written my code in `word()` because it doesn't otherwise leave an empty string.

```
> library(stringr)
> len <- length(strsplit(sentence, " ")[[1]])
> paste0(word(sentence, c(1, 2:len), c(2, 3:len)), collapse = ", ")
[1] "Jane saw, saw a, a cat, cat and, and then, then Jane, Jane sat, sat down., "
```

Can this be done without the trailing `", "` using only the `word()` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String transformation in R | Grouping words of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441766/string-transformation-in-r-grouping-words-of-a-string)

Comment: `paste0(word(sentence, -c(len:2), -c((len-1):1)), collapse = ', ')`?

Comment: @bartektartanus Are you serious?  I linked that post in this question.

Comment: paste0(word(sentence, c(2:len-1), c(2:len)), collapse = ", ")

Comment: I'll leave that here just in case you agree. The fact you are already using `strsplit` to parse the words and get their count makes the use of `word()` a little redundant. You could just stick to base R and do: `words <- unlist(strsplit(sentence, ' ')); paste(head(words, -1), tail(words, -1), collapse = ", ")`.

Comment: hmm, yes...very good point  :-).  I'm really trying to get a better feel for `word()` as it seems like it can be useful in many situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `start` and `end` arguments to `word` need to be the same length (otherwise recyling occurs) so

```
paste0(word(sentence, c(1:(len-1)), c(2:len)), collapse = ", ")
```

or

```
paste0(word(sentence, -c(len:2), -c((len-1):1)), collapse = ', ')
```

would do the trick

Comment: Thanks.  That can be a pretty handy function in string manipulation.  I just didn't think to reverse the lengths.  Cheers!