# Regex-Creating consecutive words in a sentence

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I have a string:

```
t="abc,mno,pqr,xyz,qwe,asd"
```

i want all the possible 3 consecutive words as the output, like this:

```
"abc mno pqr,mno pqr xyz,pqr xyz qwe,xyz qwe asd"
```

I am using R, so perl regex engine is to be used.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself,

```
t="abc,mno,pqr,xyz,qwe,asd"
t=gsub("(?=,([^,]*),([^,]*))", " \\1 \\2", t, perl=T)
t=gsub("(,[^,]*,[^,]*)$", "", t, perl=T)
t
"abc mno pqr,mno pqr xyz,pqr xyz qwe,xyz qwe asd"
```

Comment: i think you got some fun in asking these type of questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441766/string-transformation-in-r-grouping-words-of-a-string

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-regex possible solution

```
t <- "abc,mno,pqr,xyz,qwe,asd" 
library(zoo)
paste(rollapply(strsplit(t, ",")[[1]], width = 3, FUN = paste, collapse = " "), collapse = ",")
## [1] "abc mno pqr,mno pqr xyz,pqr xyz qwe,xyz qwe asd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another gsub method,

```
> t="abc,mno,pqr,xyz,qwe,asd"
> m <- gsub("(?=,([^,]+),([^,]+)\\b(?!$))", " \\1 \\2", t, perl=TRUE)
> result <- gsub(",(?=(?:[^,]*,)?[^,]*$)", " ", m, perl=TRUE)
> result
[1] "abc mno pqr,mno pqr xyz,pqr xyz qwe,xyz qwe asd"
```